# Rails 3, Kaminari - Error with :joins when using paginate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I have a function for prices with 2 joins and it works fine and dandy when I use it to call for prices. But now when I added Kaminari to be able to paginate, it gave me a error and I wonder if I can customize the "count*" function in Kaminari or is it my function for calling the products that's wrong?

This is in my controller

```
 @prices   = Price.select("`prices`.*").joins(:retailer, :retailer => :profile).
        where(['product_id=? AND size_id=?', params[:prod_id], params[:si_id]]).
        group(:retailer_id).order("SUM((prices.price * #{params[:amount].to_i}) + profiles.shippingCost)").page(params[:page])
```

Error code:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'retailer_id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, retailer_id AS retailer_id FROM `prices` INNER JOIN `retailers` ON `retailers`.`id` = `prices`.`retailer_id` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`retailer_id` = `retailers`.`id` WHERE (product_id='1' AND size_id='3') GROUP BY retailer_id,retailer_id ORDER BY SUM((prices.price * 1) + profiles.shippingCost)
```

When I call the products without Kaminari the MYSQL looks like this.

```
SELECT `prices`.* FROM `prices` INNER JOIN `retailers` ON `retailers`.`id` = `prices`.`retailer_id` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`retailer_id` = `retailers`.`id` WHERE (product_id='1' AND size_id='3') GROUP BY retailer_id ORDER BY SUM((prices.price * 1) + profiles.shippingCost)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If ambiguous error then try explicit syntax for retailer_id.

e.g. retailers.retailer_id ,
profiles.retailer_id ,
prices.retailer_id.

ray

Comment: Hi Ray, Thanks for your reply, but how do I do that? I mean, I don't know where the "retailer_id AS retailer_id" comes from? For what I know I haven't told it to do so?

Answer (score 0):

:retailer is duplicated inside your join clause.
Please change your join params to

> .joins(:retailer => :profile)